# Logical OR in CLIPS - simple defrule

Tags: assert, logical-operators, clips

I've just started working in CLIPS. I'm trying to do this simple rule, but i've got no idea how to use logical OR here. I know I could define two rules (one for relative-brother and other one for relative-sister) but I think it's not a point.
The rule is: You are a relative of someone, if you are his brother or sister.

```
(defrule MAIN::siblings-relatives
       (is-brother ?x ?y)
      (test (or (is-sister ?x ?y))
       =>
       (assert (is-relative ?x ?y))
       (printout t ?x " is relative of " ?y crlf))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS>
(defrule siblings-relatives
   (or (is-brother ?x ?y)
       (is-sister ?x ?y))
   =>
   (assert (is-relative ?x ?y))
   (printout t ?x " is relative of " ?y crlf))
CLIPS> (assert (is-brother Dave Jim))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (is-sister Jane Frank))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (run)
Jane is relative of Frank
Dave is relative of Jim
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (is-brother Dave Jim)
f-2     (is-sister Jane Frank)
f-3     (is-relative Jane Frank)
f-4     (is-relative Dave Jim)
For a total of 5 facts.
CLIPS>
```